# Spring - Switching from MongoDB to CouchDB and vice-versa

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, couchdb, database-migration

Having a limited knowledge of Spring, I'm wondering how easy it would be to switch from MongoDB to CouchDB or vice-versa.

At present I see benefits in both systems, and was thinking to simply test both.

Can someone help explain the steps involved and what aspects would need to be recoded?

I know with JPA / Hibernate, switching databases is easy, but I don't know if this is the case with MongoDb and CouchDb.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Those two databases are very different in terms of capabilities though?

Comment: I just recently understood that MongoDB and CouchDB have very different ways of querying the data. Most notably, CouchDB needs pre-defined views (written as javascript Map-Reduce functions), but MongoDb can query in any way you like.

Comment: Would it be possible to create the needed CouchDB views "on the fly"? That way CouchDB could be used for dynamic queries. The list of views would get quite large though... but suppose I would not mind that?

Answer (score 1):

I found this old topic but I want to point out a new project called couch-slacker. The project contains spring data implementation in standard spring data way. So if you are using spring data for mongo DB, you can easily switch implementations spring-data-mongodb by couch-slacker. If some feature you use with Mongo DB is missing, let us know on Github.

Check it out [here](https://github.com/Majlanky/couch-slacker)
Releases of the project are in maven central so it is very easy to use it.

Disclaimer: I am the founder and tech lead of the project